# Manually installing pod files

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm trying to work with a git repo who's dependencies are configured through CocoaPods. However, my internet connection is rubbish (I'm on holidays) and keeps cutting and interrupting `pod install`. I managed to install 2 of the 6 dependencies through pod (took all day) and realised I actually have the zips of these frameworks already on my computer. So I added for example `LayerKit` to my pods directory in the project folder. Then when I run `pod install` again, it hasn't noticed that I already added the file... Any idea how I can fix this or a better way I can work around this. I really have no idea how pod works, I usually just run pod install and it all works miraculously.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to create a folder under your project's main folder and place all of them in there.

Once that is done, update your target in your Podfile to look like this:

```
pod 'NameOfPod', :path => 'Relative/Path/To/Podspec'
```

That allows you to access the pods locally on your system. The path needs to point to the Podspec file for the pod. Also, make sure you do not alter the directory structure in the pods, as this will likely break them.